# How to unmarshal / deserialize collections without setters with JSON-B

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jsonb-api

I like to write my POJOs not to have setters for collections.

```
public class Parent {
    private List<Child> children;
    public List<Child> getChildren() {
        if (children == null) {
            children = new ArrayList<Child>();
        }
        return children;
    }
}

// use case example
public class ParentDecorator {
    private final Parent parent;
    public ParentDecorator(Parent parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
    public void addAll(List<Child> children) {
        parent.getChildren().addAll(children);
    }
}
```

JSON-B serialization works fine, but deserialization does not work as there is no setter for children.

**Question:** how should I fix this?

Comment: Did you find any solution, sir?

Comment: Yes. Read the answers in this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adam Bien wrote a good article [Private Fields Serialization with JSON-B and JAX-RS 2.1 / Java EE 8](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/private_fields_serialization_with_json) which I thought would fix it. The idea is to implement a custom `PropertyVisibilityStrategy` for private fields. Unfortunately it didn't work in my situation for some reason.

I made a small change to Adam's code and changed also the methods to be visible. Now my collections are deserialized.

```
/**
 * JSON-B visibility strategy for deserialization.
 * 
 * Enables JSON binding of private fields without a setter.
 */
public class JsonDeserializationStrategy implements PropertyVisibilityStrategy {

    @Override
    public boolean isVisible(Field field) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isVisible(Method method) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I only use this `PropertyVisibilityStrategy` for deserialization as the name suggests. Serialization is done with default configuration.